# Q2A: Is there a revert / undo to changes made in Admin through a PHP file?

Tags: php, function, themes, question2answer

My site is down.  I made changes INLINE in the Admin > Layout section of Question2Answer.org.  Under layout > head I put the page title.

This caused an error, I have a blank page for a site that gets a lot of traffic. Now I am thinking this is due to redundancy in the theme php or something along those lines??  But isn't there a way to access the admin section somehow?

How can I edit / revert / undo the changes (which caused the error) if I can't access the admin page where the changes were made.  Thanks for any help!

EDIT:  Through the Admin Interface, I edited Page Title and this threw me a blank page.  Is there a correlating PHP file?  Or would disabling conflicting Page titles (ones done through Theme functions) resolve it?  Can I make the Inline page title override the theme function page title?

EDIT #2:  Error log says:

> (12)Cannot allocate memory: couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for ../public_html/answers/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok!  I was able to fix this by finding and undoing the bad code via the database / phpMyAdmin